# Pattern HTML5 validation not preventing form submit when not validated

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, validation

I have an odd problem where my pattern on two numerical fields is not working properly (the form can be submitted even if the fields are not validated). The HTML looks like following:

```
        <input type="text" class="txtmin" pattern="^[+-]?\d*(\.\d+)?$" placeholder="Minimum price">

        <input type="text" class="txtmax" pattern="^[+-]?\d*(\.\d+)?$" placeholder="Maximum price">
```

When I enter something into the field, if it doesn't matches the regex, the field gets marked red, but if I try to submit the form on onclick event, the validation doesn't prevents the user to change the input value and I get an exception ...

```
$(".btnAnalyze").click(function () {
            // the form doesn't validates??
        });
```

I was trying something like this:

```
  $('txtmin').oninvalid = function (event) {
            return;
        }
```

But this doesn't do anything? Can someone help me out?

Edit: Riyad this is the full code HTML and the event I'm firing:

```
<form>
     <span class="input-group-btn">
                            <button class="btn btn-default btnGo" type="submit">Go!</button>
                        </span>

</form>

  $(".btnGo").click(function () {

            if ($('.txtSearch').val() == "") {
                ShowMessage("Please enter the search term!");
                return;
            } 
            else{
                PostAndUpdate($('.txtSearch').val(), $('input[name=type]:checked').val(), $('input[name=shipping]:checked').val(), $('input[name=condition]:checked').val(), $('.txtmin').val(), $('.txtmax').val());
            }
        });
```

Comment: are both fields inside form tag ?

Comment: @Ryad.iv no they're not, and I'm avoiding to put them inside a form tag.. Can I fix this somehow with jquery?

Comment: you need the form tag so that it can validate and block the submission otherwise you will need to validate your inputs with javascript.

Comment: I've put them inside a form tag now, submit is still allowed even if the form isnt validated properly

Comment: make sure the button is type submit and please post the full code if possible.

Comment: @Ryad.iv I made it submit now, the message gets displayed now but the even still fires even when the message appears on the field

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Clicking the button doesn't equate to submitting the form. The order of actions is:

1. Click the button
2. Fire `click` event on the button
3. If the `click` event does not cancel the event, then fire `submit` on the form
4. If the `submit` event does not cancel the event (eg. validation errors!) then proceed to submit the form

Since you're doing your work in the `click` event, the form hasn't been validated yet! You should instead do the work in the form's `submit` event.

Comment: How can I check whether the form has been validated just on a regular click event?

Comment: You can call `checkValidity()` on the form (eg. `form.checkValidity()`), which will return `true` if all elements in the form are valid.

Comment: the Dark Abosl and what about on single field only, do they have this method CheckValiditiy? or Valid()?

Comment: Yes, individual form fields have it too. But with the HTML you've provided, you really should be using the form's `submit` event instead of all this messing around.

Comment: Excellent , I'll use form instead and check the validity. Accepted ur answer ! :)

Answer (score 1):

If you expect only prices in your `input` fields, then better (i.e. most supported by browsers) approach is to use `input` of type `number` with `min` and `max` attributes:

```
<input type="number" class="txtmin" min="0.01" max="1000.00" placeholder="Minimum price">

<input type="number" class="txtmax" min="0.01" max="1000.00" placeholder="Maximum price">
```

Note that both fields have `min` and `max` attributes set, however this is not mandatory - you can restrict or not the values of every input with pure HTML this way.

Another approach is to use Javascript library like `jQuery` and perform manual validation of input.