# How to disable submit button if any html built-in regex pattern fail?

Tags: javascript, html

How to disable submit button if html built-in regex pattern fail? I can't find a solution which will loop and check all the input element. The solution has to be generic (no regex in the javascript) and the regex has to be inside the `pattern` attribute.

Right now with this code, even though the regex fails, it still triggers the button onclick event.

```js
var element = document.getElementById("submit");
element.addEventListener(
  "click",
  function () {
    console.log("btn clicked.");
  },
  false
);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<form>
  <input type="text" pattern="[A-Za-z]{3}" name="codeA" id="codeA" title="Three letter country code"><br><br>
 <input type="text" pattern="[A-Za-z]{2}" name="codeB" id="codeB" title="Two letter country code"><br><br>
  <input type="submit" id="submit">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41343859/9038475). It explains the order of events and why the click event is activated, even though the submit isn't validated, yet.

Comment: See documentation section titled [Validating against a regular expression](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Forms/Form_validation#validating_against_a_regular_expression)

Answer (score 2):

Use `checkValidity()` on each input to match the pattern. If the input check fails, disable the submit button.

```
var submitBtn = document.getElementById("submit");

submitBtn.addEventListener("click", function (event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  
  var inputs = document.querySelectorAll("input[pattern]"); // select all input elements with a pattern attribute
  
  var isValid = true;
  inputs.forEach(function (input) {
    if (!input.checkValidity()) {
      isValid = false;
    }
  });

  if (!isValid) {
    submitBtn.disabled = true;
    console.log("Some input fields are invalid. Submit button is disabled.");
  } else {
    submitBtn.disabled = false;
    console.log("All input fields are valid. Submit button is enabled.");
  }
});
```

The code uses `event.preventDefault()` to prevent submitting when the button is clicked and `document.querySelectorAll("input[pattern]")` to select all input with the pattern. Loop and check if the input matches the specified pattern by calling `checkValidity()`. If any input fail, `isValid` is set to false and the input submit button is disabled and if `isValid` is true the submit button `disabled` property is set to `false`.

Comment: Let's say for the first time, there is one textbox which fail the regex, the submit button is disabled. Then that textbox regex pass, how it re-check again since the submit button is already disabled?

Comment: Put a listner on the keyup event, with a delay, and check for validity again. If it is valid, set submitBtn.disabled = false.